# No result on table

Tags: php, mysqli

I like to retrieve a mysql result and assign to a variable ($status) 
and depending on the result I want to put an ok or a ko (in this case if $status are "Active" the result is an "ok)

Seems that the problem are when show the result into the td but can't see something else.
 
Anybody can help?

````
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $number = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $status = strtolower($row['register_status']);

        $data .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                        <td>'
                        if ($status == "Active") {
                                echo "OK";
                        }
                        else {
                                echo "KO";
                        }
                        '</td>

                        <td width="1%">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions
                                 <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Update</a></li>
                                    <li onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                                 </div>
                         </td>
                  </tr>';```


The idea is change in the future the echo for an image or a div content
````

Comment: How could $status == "Active" when $status will always be = strtolower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `echo`, which will output "OK" or "KO" before the rest of your HTML, try determining whether you need "OK"/"KO" before you create your HTML.

You could also add an image or div or whatever you want instead of "OK" or "KO".

Then just concatenate this `$value` to your string like you are doing with the rest of your `td`'s

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $number = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $status = strtolower($row['register_status']);
        if ($status == "active") {
            $value = "<div>Other Content</div>";
        }
        else {
            $value = "<img src='http://example.com/img.jpg'>";
        }
        $data .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$value.'</td>

                        <td width="1%">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions
                                 <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Update</a></li>
                                    <li onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                                 </div>
                         </td>
                  </tr>';
```

Comment: echo is to test the result but like to put an image or a div content instead

Comment: @GuifIf I've updated the answer to show how you could insert a div or image instead.

Answer (score 0):

First thing ,You are converting the status into the lower case and try to compare with "Active". It always gives you the incorrect answer every-time.

Rather than using the echo, you can first take the value of the status into one variable and than try to set under the table. It will work for you.

```
if ($status == "active") {
    $status = "OK";
}
else {
    $status = "KO";
}
$data .= '<tr>
<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
<td>'.$status.'</td>

<td width="1%">
        <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li onclick="GetUserDetails('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Update</a></li>
            <li onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
 </td>
</tr>';
```